# Proper way to get user input via GUI

Tags: java

If I use a GUI text field do I still need to use scanner?

> I have this in my GUI class to get the users input

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButton.setBounds(75, 94, 210, 32);
    getContentPane().add(startButton);

    targetInput = new JTextField();
    targetInput.setBounds(75, 50, 210, 33);
    targetInput.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    targetInput.setToolTipText("");
    getContentPane().add(targetInput);
    targetInput.setColumns(1);
```

How would I call that  in my Main class?

If I was calling from the console I would simply just import scanner and call for an input. However since it is in GUI I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do

`String input = targetInput.getText();`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the text from a `JTextField` using `getText()` method.

Ex: `String inputString = targetInput.getText();`

If you want to get the text when the button is clicked, add an `ActionListener` to the button.

Ex:

```
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String inputString = targetInput.getText();//get the text
        System.out.println(inputString);//print it
    }
});
```